# $\text {dom}(R)$ and $\text {ran}(R)$ exists for any definition of order pair.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, axioms

Suppose that we define, for any sets $x,y$, a set $(x,y)$ with the propertie that $$(x,y)=(x',y')\rightarrow x=x'\wedge y=y'(*)$$

Let $R$ be a set. I want to show that the classes $\{x:\exists y((x,y))\in R\}$ and $\{y:\exists x((x,y)\in R)\}$ exists.

**My attempt:**

Let $A:=\{z\in R: \exists v,w(z=(v,w))\}$ (this exists by separation axiom). Now take $\phi(z,u)\equiv\exists x,y(z=(x,y))\rightarrow u=x$.

It is easy to show that for each $z\in A$ exists an unique $u$ such that $\phi(z,u)$. So, by replacement axiom exists a set $B$ such that $\forall z\in A\exists u\in B\phi(z,u)$.

So, by separation axiom exists the set $\{x\in B:\exists z\in A\phi(z,x)\}=\{x:\exists y((x,y))\in R\}$ (In the same way we proof the existence of the another set).

My doubt is that I don't use $(*)$ or I don't see where I did. So, I don't know if my proof is right.

**Edit:** The only axioms that I can use are: extensionality, separation, pairing, union and replacement.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But $R$ is an arbitrary set.

Comment: So $A$ is the subset (maybe empty) of $R$ made of *pairs* ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes it is

Comment: An you do not assume any "usual" def of ordered pair, like e.g. [Kuratowski's one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory). In which case you are assuming implicitly the axiom that : for any sets $x,y$ the *pair* $(x,y)$ exists.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The idea is to show that $dom R$ and $ran R$ can be defined independent of definition of $(x,y)$

Comment: @Gödel Let me point out that you implicitly assume (and use) that the map $\langle x, y \rangle \mapsto (x,y)$ is definable. And you have to assume that. It's not enough that for every $x,y$ $(x,y)$ exists. (You could cook up an example such that $\{ (n,n) \mid n < \omega \}$ is a real that doesn't exist in $L$, even though, for every $n < \omega$, $(n,n) \in L$.)

Comment: @StefanMesken What do you mean by $\langle x,y \rangle$? Is it a particular definition of order pair?

Comment: @Gödel Let's just say it's the Kuratowski pairing of $x,y$ (it doesn't really matter but since you used $(,)$ for your new pairing, I needed to distinguish them). To put it in other words: You need that there is a paramater free formula $\phi$ such that $(x,y) = z \iff \phi(x,y,z)$ is provable in your background theory.

Comment: Then, you suggest to me drop this construction? @StefanMesken

Comment: @Gödel No, I just think you should be aware of this implicit additional assumption.

Comment: @StefanMesken If I´m fine, the only tool that I need to justify the "additional assumption" is pair, separation and  replacement axioms. It is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition.** Let $x$ and $y$ be sets. The *ordered pair* $x$ comma $y$, denoted $(x,y)$, is $\rule{50pt}{0.4pt}$.

Here $\rule{50pt}{0.4pt}$ represents any definition used.

**Remark.** Let $x$, $y$, $u$, $v$ be sets. Then $(x,y)=(u,v)$ if and only if $x=u$ and $y=v$.

Here it is assumed that the above remark can be proven, and is the assumption $\color{blue}{(*)}$ you mention.

**Proposition.** Let $R$ be a set. Then $\{x:(\exists y)[(x,y)\in R]\}$ is a set.

*Proof.*
Define the formula $\varphi$ with free variables $\check{p}$ and $\check{x}$ by
$$\varphi(\check{p},\check{x}):=(\exists y)[(\check{x},y)=\check{p}].$$
By the axiom of replacement, $\{x:(\exists p\in A)[\varphi(p,x)]\}$ is a set. Indeed,
$$\varphi:p\mapsto x$$ satisfies $(\forall a)[a\in A\:\Rightarrow\:(\exists!b)[\varphi(a,b)]]$ by $\color{blue}{(*)}$. That is to say $\varphi$ is a class function. Here $A=\{z\in R:(\exists a)(\exists b)[z=(a,b)]\}$.

$\square$

This proposition and proof can be modified to prove the range is a set as well.