# Do we need the axiom of replacement (ZFC) to define a product of structures (Universal Algebra)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, universal-algebra

Do we need the axiom of replacement (ZFC) to define a product of structures (Universal Algebra)?

Here $\mathrm{V}$ is the class of all sets.

From my perspective here is how the product of structures is defined.

**Definitions:**

Let $ X $ be a set. An *arity-relation* in $ X $ is a 2-tuple $ \left(\vphantom{n}\smash{\breve{n}},\asymp\right) $, where $ \vphantom{n}\smash{\breve{n}}\in \mathbb{N} $ and $ {\asymp}\subseteq X^{\vphantom{n}\smash{\breve{n}}} $.

Let $ X $ be a set. An *arity-operation* on $ X $ is a 2-tuple $ \left(\vphantom{n}\smash{\dot{n}},\odot\right) $, where $ \vphantom{n}\smash{\dot{n}}\in \mathbb{N} $ and $ {\odot}:X^{\vphantom{n}\smash{\dot{n}}}\to X $.

A *structure* is a 3-tuple $ \left(X,(\vphantom{n}\smash{\breve{n}},\asymp),(\vphantom{n}\smash{\dot{n}},\odot)\right) $, where $ X $ is a set and $ \{(\vphantom{n}\smash{\breve{n}}_{(\cdot)},\asymp_{(\cdot)})\} $ is a family of arity-relations in $ X $ and $ \{(\vphantom{n}\smash{\dot{n}}_{(\cdot)},\odot_{(\cdot)})\} $ is a family of  arity-operations on $ X $.

Let $ \{(X_\lambda,(m,\asymp^{\lambda}),(n,\odot^{\lambda}))\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda} $ be a family of structures.
Fix nonempty $ I\subseteq \Lambda $.
The *product* of $ (X_i,(m,\asymp^i),(n,\odot^i)) $ for $ i\in I $, denoted $ \prod_{i\in I}(X_i,(m,\asymp^i),(n,\odot^i)) $, is the 3-tuple $ \left(Y,(m,\vphantom{\asymp}\smash{\bar{\asymp}}),(n,\vphantom{\odot}\smash{\bar{\odot}})\right) $, where $ Y=\prod_{i\in I}X_i $ and

$ \vphantom{\asymp}\smash{\bar{\asymp}}_{(\cdot)}:\operatorname{dom}\left(m\right)\to \mathrm{V}:\alpha\mapsto \{y^{(\cdot)}\in Y^{m_\alpha}:\left(\forall i\in I\right)[\pi_i\circ y\in ({\asymp}^i)_\alpha]\} $ and

$ \vphantom{\odot}\smash{\bar{\odot}}_{(\cdot)}:\operatorname{dom}\left(n\right)\to\mathrm{V}:\alpha\mapsto \{(y^{(\cdot)},z)\in Y^{n_\alpha}\times Y:\left(\forall i\in I\right)[(\odot^i)_\alpha(\pi_i\circ y)=z_i]\} $.

**Question:** Can the codomain of $\bar{\asymp}_{(\cdot)}$ or $\bar{\odot}_{(\cdot)}$, currently written as $\mathrm{V}$, be described without the axiom of replacement?

**Context:** I am interested in the axiom of replacement because of how little it is required in everyday mathematics (embedded in ZFC). Originally I was looking into [Birkhoff's HSP Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)#Birkhoff%27s_theorem) in Universal Algebra where no relations beyond equality is in a structure. I simply extended the definition to include relations because that is what Model Theory studies. <s>I provide this context because I received some downvotes on this question without explanation.</s>

**EDIT1:** I want to add that I am not commited to the definition above. If you know of a different definition that can work in ZFC (minus replacement), then I will consider that an answer to the titular question. For example, the definition of an ordered pair $(a,b):=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ commonly used has the benefit of the separation axiom and power set axiom (among others) being enough to define products of sets. If one insists to define ordered pairs in an unknown fashion that so that $(a,b)=(x,y)\iff a=x\text{ and }b=y$, then the replacement axiom would be required to do much of the same things. For example, see [$\text {dom}(R)$ and $\text {ran}(R)$ exists for any definition of order pair.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988510/text-domr-and-text-ranr-exists-for-any-definition-of-order-pair/3116278#3116278)

Comment: I don't see any downvotes.

Comment: I saw it go to negative 1 when I initially posted the question, and now (with your remark) I gather it was because I had initially used both the elementary-set-theory and set-theory tag. I imagine one should not use both.

Comment: I don't know about that. I saw the question, and I've never seen it with a downvote. It might have been someone downvoting quickly and then reversing it after reading the question more carefully. In either case, you're absolutely right that you shouldn't use both the elementary set theory and the set theory tags together.

Comment: The current upvote is mine, I accidentally pressed the downvote button first, and then reversed it. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: +1 interesting question.  I don't have a direct answer for you, but I just started working on an implementation of Birkhoff's HSP theorem in dependent type theory (in Lean).  It may end up being non-constructive in the end, which is okay, but of course I don't plan to use all of ZFC, maybe just C... plus dependent types, CiC, and the standard natural deduction rules a la Gentzen.

Comment: V is indefinable  in ZFC.

Comment: @EricWofsey I will make an update shortly!

Comment: Oh, I think I see. $m$ denotes the function $\alpha\mapsto m_\alpha$, which is the same for all the structures?

Comment: Yes. "Of the same type" is often said in Universal Algebra.

Comment: Sorry for the off topic, but how do yuou wrote *I provide this context because I received some downvotes on this question without explanation* with that horizontal line ove the text?

Comment: @Minato "<s>" before and "</s>" after the text (think s equals strike)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element of the image of $\bar{\asymp}_{(\cdot)}$ or $\bar{\odot}_{(\cdot)}$ is a subset of $Y^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  That is, it is a set of functions $n\to Y$.  Every such function for any $n$ can be considered as a relation (more specifically, a partial function) from $\mathbb{N}$ to $Y$.  So, $\bar{\asymp}_{(\cdot)}$ can be considered to have codomain $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times Y))$, with no Replacement needed.

Comment: Originally I was stuck at the codomain for $\bar{\asymp}_{(\cdot)}$ being $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathrm{dom}(m)}\mathcal{P}(Y^{m_\alpha})$ but I could use $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times Y))$. The thought of considering partial functions eluded me.

Comment: One remark, though, is that Replacement is equivalent to the "general existence of Cartesian products", but of course that for the standard Kuratowski definition, Replacement is very much unnecessary. (And once you've fixed your notion of products, you only apply to some finitely many instances anyway.)